# Orientation change event in Browser on Palm webOS

Tags: javascript, mobile, webos, palm-pre

I'm working on a web application where I'm trying to capture when the user rotates the screen. Fundamentally, I want to know if the user is browsing in portrait mode or landscape mode. The iPhone/iPad and Android browsers send a resize event when the screen orientation changes.

Unfortunately, the browser in webOS doesn't seem to send that notification. Any advice on how to detect in the browser any changes in orientation on Palm webOS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it's [marked as a bug](http://developer.palm.com/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=80&t=6902) that the event isn't present and "should be fixed in an upcoming release".  You could possibly watch window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth as a workaround.